# return string[] from LINQ IQueryable object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, linq

I'm trying to work with the .NET AJAX autocompletion extension. The extension is expecting the following...

```
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
```

My database queries are in a LINQ var object. I'm getting compile-time errors about not being able to convert type IQueryable to string[].

```
InventoryDataContext assets = new InventoryDataContext();
    var assetsInStorage = from a in assets.Assets
                          where a.Name.Contains(prefixText)
                          orderby a.Name ascending
                          select new[] { a.Manufacturer.Name, a.Name };
    return (string[])assetsInStorage;
```

Comment: I suspect you need to replace **a.Name.Contains** or you'll get values like "Jim Bob" when *prefixText* is "Bob"...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it with the following..
   let concat = a.Manufacturer.Name + " " + a.Name + " (" + a.AssetID + ")" + a.ProductDivision.ProductDivision1 + a.Location.Name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get an `string[]` at first you must select only *one string property* on your query, not an anonymous object:

```
var assetsInStorage = from a in assets.Assets
                      where a.Name.Contains(prefixText)
                      orderby a.Name ascending
                      select a.Manufacturer.Name; // or a.Name
```

`assetsInStorage` at this moment is an `IEnumerable<string>`, and then you should convert it to `string[]` by:

```
return assetsInStorage.ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, I confirm this works. Is it possible to concat two fields in the select statement though?

Comment: **@John:** Thank you!, **Bay:** just concatenate them in the select: `select a.Name + " " + a.Manufacturer.Name;`

Comment: Ugh... so simple. Thanks again CMS, et al

Answer (score 1):

Your `assetsInStorage` doesn't appear to be an `IEnumerable<string>`... as such, you'd have to project your anonymous type into a string.

```
assetsInStorage.Select(a=>a[0] + a[1])
```

(Or however you want to convert that anonymouns type to a string.)

And then you can return `.ToArray()`:

```
return assetsInStorage.Select(a=>a[0]+a[1]).ToArray();
```

Comment: It is an `IEnumerable<T>` since `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yes but T is not a string but an anonymous type

Comment: T is not an anonymous type but a string array.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
InventoryDataContext assets = new InventoryDataContext();
var assetsInStorage = from a in assets.Assets                          
   where a.Name.Contains(prefixText)
   orderby a.Name ascending
   select String.Concat(x.ManufacturerName, " ", x.Name);    

return assetsInStorage.ToArray();
```

EDITED based on comment... EF is able to interpret String.Concat(), so the additional enumeration wasn't necessary.

Comment: The ToList() not necessary, no matter which of those frameworks you're using. The ToArray() call at the end will cause the result set to be enumerated before the underlying connection is closed anyway - there's no point to forcing enumeration twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single array that contains both `a.Manufacturer.Name` and `a.Name` for each of the assets, you can do that with a slight modification of CMS's answer:

```
var assetsInStorage = from a in assets.Assets
                      where a.Name.Contains(prefixText)
                      orderby a.Name ascending
                      select new[] { a.Manufacturer.Name, a.Name };
```

At this point, `assetsInStorage` is an `IEnumerable<string[]>` which also counts as an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`. We can flatten this down to a single `IEnumerable<string>` using `SelectMany` and then turn it into an array.

```
return assetsInStorage.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
```

In this way, you're not required to select only a single string value.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
return assetsInStorage.ToArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue that the Enumerable<T> is not of a string but an anonymous type holding an array of two strings

Comment: Oops. I was viewing this on my iPhone and it truncated the line and I didn't see the second parameter being passed in there ... that'll teach me!

Comment: @John - Actually, the OP's code is not creating an anonymous type holding an array of two strings - it's just an array of two strings. So the output is `IEnumerable<string[]>`.